# Loading several FITS files using the HARPS-N data set of CCF files via Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to load several FITS files using the HARPS-N data set of CCF files.

r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:20:10.645_CCF_A.fits

This is not cubed data, it is in the following structure.

r.HARPN.2018-01-18T14:20:10.645_CCF_A.fits
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     818   ()
1  SCIDATA       1 ImageHDU        10   (49, 70)   float32
2  ERRDATA       1 ImageHDU        10   (49, 70)   float32
3  QUALDATA      1 ImageHDU        10   (49, 70)   int32

I have attempted several ways of doing this via python.  I would like to replicate the images (spectrum, mesh plot ect) below which was created in MATLAB (someone else's example)

[image]

I just can't seem to nail this.

Thankyou